# Strong law of large numbers and the probability that something exists.

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

The strong law of large numbers states that if $X$ is a RV and $X_1, X_2 \ldots$ are independent and identically distributed copies of $X$, and $\overline{X}_n= \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + \ldots + X_n)$, and the first moment of $X$ is finite, then

$P(\lim_{n\to\infty} \overline{X}_n = \Bbb E X) =1$.

But by definition of limit this means that is almost certain that for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $n_0$ such that $n>n_0 \implies |\overline{X}_n - \Bbb E X|<\epsilon$.

What meaning can we give to "the probability that something exists" (in this case $n_0$)?

Comment: Don't forget that $n_0$ is a random variable itself and depends on $\omega$.

Comment: The SLLN does not claim that _all_ realizations of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n, \ldots$ have the property that the sequence $s_n = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_n$ converges to $\mathbb EX$. It says that the set of realizations for which $s_n$ converges to _something else_ or _does not converge at all_ has probability $0$. It is an event of probability $0$ but it is _not_ the empty set.